# Failed to execute 'transferOut' on 'USBDevice': The specified endpoint is not part of a claimed and selected alternate interface

Tags: javascript, webusb

I am having some difficulty with the transferOut to my Star TSP thermal printer.  My code is working on one PC but on another I am getting the error: 'Failed to execute 'transferOut' on 'USBDevice': The specified endpoint is not part of a claimed and selected alternate interface.'

My code is below:

```
$(document)
    .on("click",
        ".request-device",
        async function () {

            try {
                device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x0519 }] })

                await device.open()
                    .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
                    .then(() => device.claimInterface(device.configuration.interfaces[0].interfaceNumber))
                var string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
                string += "\x1B\x64\x02";//Paper cutting code

                var encoder = new TextEncoder();
                var data = encoder.encode(string);
                await device.transferOut(1, data)
                    .catch(error => { console.log(error); })
            } catch (error) {
                alert('Error: ' + error.message);
            }
        });
```

I am really stumped, tried changing the endpoint parameter of transferOut to different numbers with no success.  I have also changed the drivers on the printers on both PCs to use winusb.sys.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at the endpoints in `device.configuration.interfaces`?

Comment: Figured out that the out endpoint is 2.  Changed it over and it is no longer throwing an error, transferOut is returning a status of 'ok' but unfortunately nothing is printing